# Run Subset Data Before Performing Math Operation Based on Row Value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, summary

I am trying to figure out an optimized way to perform math operations based on row identifier.

Sample data set as follows:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
```

I want to find sum of rows based on column `A`. So, final output will have four rows:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8
2   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8
3   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8
4   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8   4   8
```

Since, the real data set is large. I am not able to think clearly as to how I can traverse through all the data set and get the desired operation done. `sum` above is just an example, I will do more complex operation. Key is to subset data based on row key and then perform operation, store and then keep doing it till last row key is reached.

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution from `dplyr`. If you want to have a more complex operation, such as apply different functions to different columns. `summarise_at` or `summarise_if` could be more suitable than `summarise_all`. But it is not possible to develop a specific solution until we see a good reproducible example and problem statement of that situation.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(.)))

dt2
# A tibble: 5 x 11
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J     K
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     1     4     8     4     4     8     4     8     4     4     8
3     2     4     8     4     4     8     4     8     4     4     8
4     3     4     8     4     4     8     4     8     4     4     8
5     4     4     8     4     4     8     4     8     4     4     8
```

#### Update

Here is a base R method from @Wen

```
dt2 <- aggregate(.~ A, data = dt, FUN = sum)
```

And a solution from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt2 <- setDT(dt)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = A]
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 3   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2
                 4   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   2",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Wen Me neither.

Comment: @Wen - The data I have has non-zero values. I just wrote `0` for cleaner reproducible data here and those values are just used for complex math I wrote in the question above.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil Then I think , by using ycw's answer could solve your problem ~

Comment: @ycw - Thanks. What if can't use use `dplyr` due to system issues? Possible to do with base packages? I am on enterprise version of Spotfire (`TERR`) based tool, which has issues with `dplyr`, why I don't know.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil then you can try `aggdata <- aggregate(.~ A, data = dt, FUN = sum)`

Comment: @Wen Thanks for providing the base R method. With your permission, I would like to add this as an update to my post.